# Variance of Random Vector in the Circular Orthogonal Ensemble

Tags: covariance-matrix, circular-statistics, random-matrix, orthogonal

Let $x$ be a (uniformly) randomly chosen column of a random orthogonal matrix (of size $K$ x $K$) distributed according to Haar measure. What is $\mathbb{E}[x]$, $\mathbb{E}[x x^T]$, $Cov(x, x)$, and $Var(x x^T)$?

It seems we can calculate this if we can compute the first four raw moments of $x_i$ for some index $i$.